# Formatting Main Part of Number While Keeping the decimal part untouched in VBA

Tags: vba

I need to format the main part (whole) of a number without touching or affecting the decimal part:

```
12345.123456 becomes 12,345.123456

123.123 becomes 123.123

12345678.123 becomes 12,345,678.123

123 becomes 123
```

The fractional part length is variable in length of decimal places and need to be kept untouched (as is).

The formatting applies only to the whole number. Formatting the whole number is simple, but how to not affect the decimal part.

The Format parameter should work with any length of decimal places.

I am using the following:

```
Format(123456789.12345,"#,#.#############################")
```

However, the only problem with this solution is:

1. There is always an assumption on the maximum possible number of decimal places by the number of # used.
2. If the number is without a fraction say "123.0" or "123", the output will be "123." always with a decimal separator (dot).

Thanks

Comment: Break into two parts: whole and fractional, format the whole number, put the two parts back together when you print.

Comment: @nicomp thanks. I am trying to get the Format function to do this rather than do the alternatives.

Comment: Is this a limitation of the "Format" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @nicomp said you'll want to break this into two parts.

```
dim num as string 'or a double converted to a string
dim nums() as string 'array

num = 123456789.123456

nums = split(num, ".") 'break into array at decimal
nums(0) = format(nums(0), "###,###") 'format whole numbers
num = nums(0) & "." & nums(1) 'recombine
```

This should add a comma after every three whole numbers

Comment: What if you use num=1.0    what will be result?

Comment: Will come back as 1.0

Comment: Tried it with 1.1 it works. Tried it with 1.0 and 1 it gives Subscript out of range

Comment: ahh yeah if you use just a whole number you will need to do a check before the split to see if it has a decimal otherwise the split will error out.

Comment: I guess it is not doable using the Format function.

It seems to be a limitation of the Format function. The whole part may be stated as variable in digit length but the decimal (fraction) part must be stated as fixed digits.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks again to all.

Comment: Voted up because you cited me and mostly because @Warcupine is the best handle ever.

Comment: @Warcupine it works but I want to do it with "Format"

Comment: That code uses format, It just needs to be split because it doesn't seem to be able to handle the decimal with a dynamic amount of places.

Comment: If we put # on the left of a decimal point it is unlimited number of digits. If we put # on the right of a decimal point it will be fixed digits. Who decided this be correct ? Microsoft ? and wy? Some programmer decided this 30 years ago and we are stuck with his stupid logic.

Comment: I have no clue as to their reasoning